# C++/CX No Suitable Copy Constructor

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, c++-cx

I have a problem with C++/CX. I'm trying to create a class that is actually a collection of other Class. The class is declared here in the header file:

```
#pragma once
namespace AdeptlyAdaptiveLayout
{

   public ref class NewsItem sealed
   {
   public:
    NewsItem(int init_Id, Platform::String^ init_Category, Platform::String^ init_Headline, Platform::String^ init_Subhead, Platform::String^ init_DateLine, Platform::String^ Image);
    property int Id;
    property Platform::String^ Category;
    property Platform::String^ Headline;
    property Platform::String^ Subhead;
    property Platform::String^ DateLine;
    property Platform::String^ Image;
   };

   public ref class NewsItemCollection sealed
   {
   public:
    Platform::Collections::Vector<NewsItem> getNewsItems();
   };
}
```

and this is the source file

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "NewsItem.h"

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Platform::Collections;

namespace AdeptlyAdaptiveLayout
{
    NewsItem::NewsItem(int init_Id,
        String^ init_Category,
        String^ init_Headline,
        String^ init_Subhead,
        String^ init_DateLine,
        String^ init_Image)
    {
        Id = init_Id;
        Category = init_Category;
        Headline = init_Headline;
        Subhead = init_Subhead;
        DateLine = init_DateLine;
        Image = init_Image;
    }

    Vector<NewsItem> NewsItemCollection::getNewsItems()
    {
        Vector<NewsItem> temp;

        temp.Append(*ref new NewsItem(1, "Financial", "Lorem Ipsum", "doro sit amet", "Nunc tristique nec", "Assets/Financial1.png"));
        temp.Append(*ref new NewsItem(2, "Financial", "Etiam ac felis viverra", "vulputate nisl ac, aliquet nisi", "tortor porttitor, eu fermentum ante congue", "Assets/Financial2.png"));
        temp.Append(*ref new NewsItem(3, "Financial", "Integer sed turpis erat", "Sed quis hendrerit lorem, quis interdum dolor", "in viverra metus facilisis sed", "Assets/Financial3.png"));
        temp.Append(*ref new NewsItem(4, "Financial", "Proin sem neque", "aliquet quis ipsum tincidunt", "Integer eleifend", "Assets/Financial4.png" ));
        temp.Append(*ref new NewsItem(5, "Financial", "Mauris bibendum non leo vitae tempor", "In nisl tortor, eleifend sed ipsum eget", "Curabitur dictum augue vitae elementum ultrices", "Assets/Financial5.png" ));

        temp.Append(*ref new NewsItem(6, "Food", "Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit amet", "Nunc tristique nec", "Assets/Food1.png" ));
        temp.Append(*ref new NewsItem(7, "Food", "Etiam ac felis viverra", "vulputate nisl ac, aliquet nisi", "tortor porttitor, eu fermentum ante congue",  "Assets/Food2.png" ));
        temp.Append(*ref new NewsItem(8,"Food", "Integer sed turpis erat", "Sed quis hendrerit lorem, quis interdum dolor", "in viverra metus facilisis sed","Assets/Food3.png" ));
        temp.Append(*ref new NewsItem(9, "Food","Proin sem neque", "aliquet quis ipsum tincidunt", "Integer eleifend", "Assets/Food4.png" ));
        temp.Append(*ref new NewsItem(10, "Food", "Mauris bibendum non leo vitae tempor", "In nisl tortor, eleifend sed ipsum eget", "Curabitur dictum augue vitae elementum ultrices", "Assets/Food5.png" ));

        return temp;
    }

}
```

The problem is that I keep having this error message "class 'AdeptlyAdaptiveLayout::NewsItem' has no suitable copy constructor". I don't have any idea what I've done wrong. Can you guys me a clue?

Comment: Why use `ref new` when you just want the object, why not do `temp.Append(NewsItem(...))` directly?

Comment: As for your problem, I don't know the specifics of C++/CX, but it seems that the compiler can't generate a default implicit copy-constructor for the class, you need to explicitly create a copy-constructor. When passing an object to the `Append` function, a *copy* is made to store in the vector, if the compiler can't create that copy then you will get an error like the one you have.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer now. I've changed the type from Vector to IVector, explicitly create the copy constructor, and adding several changes in the implementation. Here is the changed code in the header and in the source.

Header:

```
namespace AdeptlyAdaptiveLayout
{

    public ref class NewsItem sealed
    {
    public:
        NewsItem(int init_Id, Platform::String^ init_Category, Platform::String^ init_Headline, Platform::String^ init_Subhead, Platform::String^ init_DateLine, Platform::String^ Image);
        NewsItem(NewsItem^ obj);
        property int Id;
        property Platform::String^ Category;
        property Platform::String^ Headline;
        property Platform::String^ Subhead;
        property Platform::String^ DateLine;
        property Platform::String^ Image;
    };

    public ref class NewsItemCollection sealed
    {
    public:
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<NewsItem^>^ getNewsItems();
    };
}
```

Source:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "NewsItem.h"

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Platform::Collections;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;

namespace AdeptlyAdaptiveLayout
{
    NewsItem::NewsItem(int init_Id,
        String^ init_Category,
        String^ init_Headline,
        String^ init_Subhead,
        String^ init_DateLine,
        String^ init_Image)
    {
        Id = init_Id;
        Category = init_Category;
        Headline = init_Headline;
        Subhead = init_Subhead;
        DateLine = init_DateLine;
        Image = init_Image;
    }

    NewsItem::NewsItem(NewsItem^ obj)
    {
        this->Category = obj->Category;
        this->DateLine = obj->DateLine;
        this->Headline = obj->Headline;
        this->Id = obj->Id;
        this->Image = obj->Image;
        this->Subhead = obj->Subhead;
    }

    IVector<NewsItem^>^ NewsItemCollection::getNewsItems()
    {
        IVector<NewsItem^>^ temp = ref new Vector<NewsItem^> ();

        temp->Append(ref new NewsItem(1, "Financial", "Lorem Ipsum", "doro sit amet", "Nunc tristique nec", "Assets/Financial1.png"));
        temp->Append(ref new NewsItem(2, "Financial", "Etiam ac felis viverra", "vulputate nisl ac, aliquet nisi", "tortor porttitor, eu fermentum ante congue", "Assets/Financial2.png"));
        temp->Append(ref new NewsItem(3, "Financial", "Integer sed turpis erat", "Sed quis hendrerit lorem, quis interdum dolor", "in viverra metus facilisis sed", "Assets/Financial3.png"));
        temp->Append(ref new NewsItem(4, "Financial", "Proin sem neque", "aliquet quis ipsum tincidunt", "Integer eleifend", "Assets/Financial4.png" ));
        temp->Append(ref new NewsItem(5, "Financial", "Mauris bibendum non leo vitae tempor", "In nisl tortor, eleifend sed ipsum eget", "Curabitur dictum augue vitae elementum ultrices", "Assets/Financial5.png" ));

        temp->Append(ref new NewsItem( 6, "Food", "Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit amet", "Nunc tristique nec", "Assets/Food1.png" ));
        temp->Append(ref new NewsItem(7, "Food", "Etiam ac felis viverra", "vulputate nisl ac, aliquet nisi", "tortor porttitor, eu fermentum ante congue",  "Assets/Food2.png" ));
        temp->Append(ref new NewsItem(8,"Food", "Integer sed turpis erat", "Sed quis hendrerit lorem, quis interdum dolor", "in viverra metus facilisis sed","Assets/Food3.png" ));
        temp->Append(ref new NewsItem(9, "Food","Proin sem neque", "aliquet quis ipsum tincidunt", "Integer eleifend", "Assets/Food4.png" ));
        temp->Append(ref new NewsItem(10, "Food", "Mauris bibendum non leo vitae tempor", "In nisl tortor, eleifend sed ipsum eget", "Curabitur dictum augue vitae elementum ultrices", "Assets/Food5.png" ));

        return temp;
    }

}
```

However, I still do not understand why it works. I think I'm going to do an in-depth research on this.

Answer (score 0):

When you provided the constructor with this constructor signature:

```
NewsItem(int init_Id, Platform::String ....
```

... the compiler will no longer synthesize the default ctors for you. You now need to specify them yourself in this case.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s16xw1a8.aspx

> If any non-default constructors are declared, the compiler does not
>   provide a default constructor

Comment: The link and rule applies to C++ and C++ classes. Is this true for C++/CX ref classes as well?

Comment: Yes, it is. The behavior is consistent. I believe this is true for GCC and GCC variants as well, but I can't test it right now... I have a 8 week old sleeping on my lap.

Comment: I don't think that GCC implements C++/CX. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: I meant GCC w/ "normal" C++. I believe it will have the same behavior - i.e. this isn't a CX thing.

Comment: This question isn't about C++, though, it specifically asks for a **ref** class. Ref classes map to COM objects that C++/CX automatically generates, and it could use an arbitrary set of rules. Since the underlying COM object of a ref class is available to languages like JavaScript, following C++ rules seems fairly arbitrary. I don't know what rules apply with respect to C++/CX, and your answer doesn't really address this either.